# ServerSide JavaScript Transaction - Marklogic

Tags: transactions, marklogic, atomic, rollback, serverside-javascript

Is there a way in server side javascript in marklogic where I can prove that the statements within a single transaction can view the updates of each other.
And when the transaction gets rolled back, the updates are not visible outside.
Basically I wanted to prove that we can write multiple statements within a single transaction, that can see the updates of each other just like how it works in case of Xquery(statements separated by ";")

I tried xdmp.eval, but that doesnt work. Because we have an option **isolation** which can take one of 2 values - either **same-statement** or **different-transaction**.
When I give same-statement, another statements in the transaction are not able to view the update made through same-statement.
When I use different-transaction, the whole logic wont work.Because then the statement itself becomes a different transaction.

What I wanted is a single transaction with multiple lines of statements, with each line able to view the updates of other lines/statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Multi-statement Transaction in Marklogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282962/javascript-multi-statement-transaction-in-marklogic)

Comment: The solution to the question in the post  doesn't work

Comment: @sharu I have a hunch about the problem you ran into with your xdmp.eval code using `different-transaction`. Can you post the code you tried?